# Upgrading to django 1.9 AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, python-2.7

I'm migrating my project to 1.9 version, and when try to execute gives me that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 324, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/prueba/djcode/spid/preventivos/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Could you show your models.py?

Comment: Why do you need `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` in your `preventivos/__init__.py` file?

Comment: link ain't working (remove %29 in domain)

Comment: I inherited the project that way, it was started in django 1.5 and I was upgrading it, in preventivos/ __ init__.py it has defined the functions for user activity logging.

Comment: is very extensive, so I share it in this link https://pastebin.com/sDZxNVES

Comment: I didn't any change but the traceback has changed. https://pastebin.com/Epuyi5bM

Answer (score 1):

Things have changed since Django < 1.9. I had the same problem while upgrading from Django 1.6 to 1.9. This helped me out:

> It is no longer possible to have multiple installed applications with
>   the same label. In previous versions of Django, this didn’t always
>   work correctly, but didn’t crash outright either.
>
> If you have two apps with the same label, you should create an
>   AppConfig for one of them and override its label there. You should
>   then adjust your code wherever it references this application or its
>   models with the old label.
>
> It isn’t possible to import the same model twice through different
>   paths any more. As of Django 1.6, this may happen only if you’re
>   manually putting a directory and a subdirectory on PYTHONPATH. Refer
>   to the section on the new project layout in the 1.4 release notes for
>   migration instructions.
>
> You should make sure that:
>
> - All models are defined in applications that are listed in INSTALLED_APPS or have an explicit app_label.
> - Models aren’t imported as a side-effect of loading their application. Specifically, you shouldn’t import models in the root
>     module of an application nor in the module that define its
>     configuration class. Django will enforce these requirements as of
>     version 1.9, after a deprecation period.

Source: http://django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases/1.7.html#standalone-scripts